# appcelerator facebook get username

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, appcelerator-titanium

How can I gett the facebook username of a user via appcelerator facebook login

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = "153xx364563xxxx";
fb.permissions = ['publish_stream']; // Permissions your app needs
fb.forceDialogAuth = true;
fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
if (e.success) {
    Ti.API.info("Success " + JSON.stringify(e));
    alert('Logged In');
} else if (e.error) {
    alert(e.error);
} else if (e.cancelled) {
    alert("Canceled");
}
});
```

all I get is the id and name

```
Success {"success":true,"code":0,"data":"{\"name\":\"John Smith\",\"id\":\"10111182454657222\"}","uid":"10111182454657222","cancelled":false,"bubbles":true,"type":"login","source":{"id":"facebook","appid":"153xx364563xxxx","forceDialogAuth":true},"cancelBubble":false}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `publish_stream` permission is deprecated since many years, and there is no way to get the `username` anymore. The replacement for `publish_stream` would be `publish_actions`, but you only need that permission to post to the user wall.

Changelog for v2.0:

> /me/username is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

You do not need the username anyway, just use the (App Scoped) ID to identify returning users.